# Trouble saving FileStream to bucket using fireabse admin SDK and busboy

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage, filestream, firebase-admin, busboy

Using the help of `busboy` I am attempting to save `FileStream` into a Firebase bucket.

code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const userFilesBucket = admin.storage().bucket(USER_FILES_BUCKET_NAME);


function handlePost(req, res){
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })

  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    file.on('data', function(data) {
    });
    file.on('end', function() {
      uploadFile({filename: filename, file:file, mimetype:mimetype})
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("attemptFileUpload | err:", err)
          reject(err)
        });
    });
  });
}

function uploadFile(fileContainer){

  const filePath = fileContainer.filename

  const file = userFilesBucket.file(filePath);

  file.save(fileContainer.file, function(err) {
    if (!err) console.log('Sucess | uploaded a blob or file!');
  });
}
```

This will succeed and the file is saved to bucket but at the same time the above Promise catches exception:

`The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object`

as well as the files are corrupt.
This error tells me I should convert the FileStream to Buffer?

I should also note, that the `fileContainer.file` is of type FileSream.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple, a miss-read of busboy doc on my part.

Needed to use busboy's `file.on(data)` listener to access the file data as Buffer, not the original incoming file as FileStream.

```
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  file.on('data', data => {
    uploadFile({filename: filename, file:data, mimetype:mimetype})
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("attemptFileUpload | err:", err)
      });
  });
  file.on('end', function() {
      // move from here, up to file.on(data)
  });
});
```